# Firefox can't access places.sqlite after I tampered with /home/.../.mozilla

Tags: firefox

I had done it before, copy an older .mozilla folder from a hard drive on which I keep some backups so I can access an older configuration of my firefox, but apparently this new Quantum version doesn't make it possible anymore. Anyway, I copied the latest version of the folder back, and I received a message saying that firefox can't access my bookmarks and history. I tried recursively changing the permission on the folder to my current user, but it still says the same thing. Any idea where to go from here?

Comment: This is very specific about Firefox - maybe a bug report or a look in their forums would help you better

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience, since at least 2015, possibly longer, Firefox and its derivative, SeaMonkey, have methods of detecting "tampering" of places.sqlite and other similar files, and will consider them "corrupted" even if they've been copied elsewhere, the original altered, and the copy copied back.

Fortunately, you can usually save your bookmarks, at least, by renaming places.sqlite (so Firefox can create a fresh one), and then importing your bookmarks from the copy you had in another folder.  This worked for me as recently as 2016, though I can't guarantee that it will still work -- Mozilla likes to change things and make their data as inaccessible as possible (who do they think they are, Microsoft?).